# MAMP couldn't start on system startup

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to check the option to run the MAMP on mac startup, but it always fail to save.

Any suggestions?

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it back, but same as it's.

I use MAMP Pro 5.0.1

[image: MAMP Error]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin rights withyour Mac account? If not, try it with an admin account.